# How can we create a 'check Success' output in Excel VBO BO for BluePrism?

Tags: vba, blueprism

So I have a robot which is accessing an Excel file an writing some information to it from a collection.
The thing is it's been working fine so far but the other day there was an Outage and the internet connection was failing.
So bot kept running and adding the data to the excel. But the save was failing since the file is stored on a shared hard disk, so you need internet to access it. 
Bot thought it has saved but it wasn't. Can I add VBA code to the original BluePrism 'Close Workbook' to include an output as check Success? to guarantee I know it has indeed saved the file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

> Can I add VBA code to the original BluePrism 'Close Workbook' to include an output as check Success? to guarantee I know it has indeed saved the file.

You can, but the ideal approach is to try and minimize the amount of edits required to the stock VBOs as much as possible to avoid accruing technical debt. In fact, the check you're describing is possible with just the stock actions provided in the MS Excel VBO.

Instead of using the "Close Workbook" action's "Save Data" parameter to save the workbook, insert an action stage calling the MS Excel VBO's "Save Workbook As" action. You can pass the same path you've provided to the "File path" input of the "Open Workbook" action to overwrite (performing the same function as the "Save Workbook" action).

The difference is that if there's an issue saving to the specified path, the action itself will throw an `Internal` exception, which you can `Recover` and `Resume` from as your business logic dictates:

[image]